# overriding open var with available: <unknown>:0: error: 'xxx' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, overriding

I'd like to observe the `didSet` of a property that is only available on newer iOS versions. I tried:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    override open var prefersLargeTitles: Bool {
        didSet {
            print(prefersLargeTitles)
        }
    }
}
```

But I got:

> <unknown>:0: error: 'prefersLargeTitles' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a)
Swift 4.1
iOS Deployment Target 9.0
iPhone SE 11.4 Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why `didSet` is incompatible with `@available`, but I found a workaround with `get`+`set` that builds without errors:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override open var prefersLargeTitles: Bool {
    get {
        return super.prefersLargeTitles
    }
    set {
        super.prefersLargeTitles = newValue
        // `didSet` logic here:
        print(prefersLargeTitles)
    }
}
```